# how does infrastructure as a service work in cloud providers like aws and azure?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, iaas

How does  IAAS make sure clients' network/storage do not run into each other?
e.g. a  client having a same internal private ip addresses as others? 
I'm not able to find resources in the architecture behind cloud computing? I might be not looking or searching for right words.

Are all block storage authenticated?

Does every VM have a "client's tag" associated with it? 
What is technology behind it

Comment: negative voter care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain AWS. Here firstly you need to create a VPC [virtual private cloud] and all your resources are a part of a VPC and this VPC is ofcourse tagged to your account.

For detailed architecture; you can read openstack.org .. If you have like set of servers --> using openstack you can create your own AWS/Azure.